# javax.management in Android

Tags: java, android, jena

I am using a library (ARQ, with Jena), that uses `javax.management.ObjectName`. Sadly, it appears that the package `javax.management` is not included in android.

Has anyone else faced (and successfully bypassed) this issue? Pointers will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I have no solution but I'm curious as to how you would access the JMX on an android device?  Is this for doing IPC between Android apps?

Comment: I think this question belongs on the Jena mailing list - see what the purpose of that usage is, and if it can be moved to a separate jena-management jar instead.  A cursory look through the Jena and ARQ source code shows that the core Jena model/query/graph usage does not use it.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue while trying to use [Apache MINA SSHD client](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd), which relies on javax.management Exceptions wrappers (such as javax.management.MBeanException, javax.management.ReflectionException).

After some search, it seems that using `javax.management:jmx` from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.management/jmx works just fine.
I just had to add the following to my `settings.gradle`, under `google()` and `mavenCentral()` repositories :

```
maven {
    url 'https://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/'
}
```

Then, adding the following dependency to `build.gradle` did the trick!

```
implementation 'javax.management:jmx:1.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the project [androjena](https://code.google.com/p/androjena/) and its sub-project [ARQoid](https://code.google.com/p/androjena/wiki/ARQoid).
These are ports of jena and ARQ to android that I have successfully used in a project porting software to Android that is based on jena. I cannot say, though, how complete/correct/up-to-date the port is with respect to the orginals